# Cutting off UILabel symbols in some fonts because of symbols parameters in fonts

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

I've noticed that, in some fonts, some symbols are displayed incorrectly in UILabel if the frame size for them is determined by NSAttributedString.size or boundingRectWithSize. For example, I chose font AvenirNext-Bold, symbol "A", and set pointSize to 300. Calculated the frame(width = 218.69999999999999, height = 409.80000000000001). I put that character in the frame of the above size.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the parts that cut off of displayed Label are highlighted in the red boxes. I checked several other fonts and noticed that it happens all the time. Can I get rid of this without having to change the frame for the UILabel and correcting margins for symbols in fonts? Using a third-party program, I found out that, for the font AvenirNext-Bold, for the character "A", left and right margins are equal to -1.39.

[image]

Does anybody know any techniques to resolve this?

Additional:

[image]

If you open Fonts application on your MAC OS, and find Avenir Next Bold font, you can see this cutting off.

Code:

```
NSString *text = @"A";
NSString *fontName = @"AvenirNext-Bold";

CGFloat pointSize = 300.f;

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:pointSize];

CGSize size = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil].size;

self.label.text = text;
self.label.font = font;

self.label.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - size.width) / 2.f, (self.view.bounds.size.height - size.height) / 2.f, size.width, size.height);
```

Additional font:
You can change font to BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-BookIta.

Comment: Have you tried 'label.clipToBounds = false'

Comment: David Williames, yes I tried.

Comment: Please show actual code needed to reproduce.

Comment: matt, here the code to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you've noticed here is essentially the same phenomenon that I note [in my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_uilabel), that these size calculations, such as `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` and NSAttributedString's `size`, ignore margins.

You can probably work around the problem in this case by supplying your own extra margin (though how you can calculate the amount, other than arbitrarily, escapes me):

```
NSString *text = @"A";
NSString *fontName = @"AvenirNext-Bold";
CGFloat pointSize = 300.f;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:pointSize];
CGFloat margin = 10;

NSMutableAttributedString* s = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
[s addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0,s.length)];
NSMutableParagraphStyle* p = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
p.firstLineHeadIndent = margin;
p.tailIndent = -margin; // in case of right alignment
[s addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:p range:NSMakeRange(0,s.length)];
CGSize size = [s size];

self.label.attributedText = s;
self.label.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - size.width) / 2.f, (self.view.bounds.size.height - size.height) / 2.f, size.width+margin*2, size.height);
```

Comment: Thank you matt for your example, 
Unfortunately this solution does not fix all problems. If you set parameter textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight; you can see that the symbol is still clipped.

Comment: So don't do that. I already told you the margins are ignored. If you run the code I gave you, the glyph looks fine. Don't tell me it's my fault if you run some other code instead.

Comment: Your code is working correctly. But unfortunately it does not solve all problems. I'm looking for a solution that would be universal for all fonts, which can contain such problems with the characters, regardless of other parameters (textAlignment and another).

Comment: I'm sure you are. But I don't have that. I _said_ in my answer that there seems to be a bug. Stop ragging me, please; I was just trying to help. You've raised an interesting problem but there is no magic bullet. If you think this is an issue, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Besides, dealing with right alignment is trivial: just insert this line: `p.tailIndent = -margin;` You have to do _some_ of the work here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, matt. I'll try to ask Apple about this issue.